# How does IE decide which certificates to present

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl

How does IE decide which certificates to present when the server requires a client certificate?  It doesn't let me pick from all of my personal certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks for the list of certification authorities presented by the server (in its TLS `CertificateRequest` message) and should offer a sub-selection of your personal certificates that are issues by one of these CAs (it may also match certificates for which there is a path to one of these CAs via a intermediate CA it knows).

Comment: In this case our server (Big-IP F5) is setup to not present any certificates.  IE is still showing a selection, but I'm not totally sure how it picks them.

Comment: If it's not using re-negotiation, the full handshake should be visible. You can intercept the traffic with Wireshark and see what the `CertificateRequest` packet contains, to make sure it's configured as requested.